# Enviar mismo JSON varias request pero con distinto valor en un nodo via POST con Apache JMeter

Tags: json, test, rendimiento, jmeter

Hola a todos y todas y todes :) espero estén todos bien y cuidándose. Por favor necesito una ayuda si es posible.

Les cuento que estoy probando el comportamiento y rendimiento de un endpoint y tengo un JSON para probarlo, entonces estoy enviando vía HTTP POST dicho JSON con Apache JMeter. Al enviar una sola request no hay ningún problema (porque es una sola) pero necesito hacer una prueba de carga más intensa (por ejemplo 50 request por segundo) para probar el rendimiento de dicho endpoint con mayor carga, entonces mi pregunta es la siguiente ¿será posible iterar por ejemplo esas 50 veces por el mismo JSON y reemplazar el valor de un nodo de este por un numero distinto cada vez antes de enviar cada request y así poder enviar en cada request el mismo JSON pero con valor distinto en dicho nodo?. Soy nuevo en JMeter pero he visto que tiene una funcionalidad que se llama PreProcessor (pre procesador) pero no se como se implementa.

Este es el cuerpo del JSON y el nodo específico al cual debería poder asignarle un valor distinto para cada request .

Les agradezco cualquier ayuda saludos a toda la comunidad 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Sí, se puede. Una opción es hacerle caso a la respuesta de Vadim. Al definir la petición que se envía en el jmx de JMeter, es posible decirle que use una variable para el id y definirla así.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puede usar la función Random en lugar de `"id": 999995`:

```
"id": ${__Random(100000,999999,RandomID)}
```

Comment: Este sitio usa preguntas y respuestas en Español.